get_the_post_thumbnail_url() not showing my featured image
I'm stuck right now trying to figure out why my featured image is not showing as my header background image.
Here is what i have so far:
<?php
            function featured_img_url() {
                if (has_post_thumbnail() and is_singular()) {
                    $gs_thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_post(), 'thumbnail' );
                    echo 'background-image: url(' . $gs_thumbnail_url . '); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:contain;';
                }
            }
        ?>

    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <div class="featured-image" style="<?php featured_img_url();?>">
        <header class="page-title theme-bg-light py-5">
            <h1 class="heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <!--<img class="header-img" src="wp-content/themes/gary-schoeniger-llc/assets/images/gs-new-book.jpeg" alt="header-image">-->
        </header>
        </div>

In my stylesheet I have this:
.featured-image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
}

I tried multiple varieties of how to display it and they still don't display. Looking at the Developer Tools on the site to check to see if the values are there, they're there but won't show.

Is image not appearing at all or shown as small thumbnail? I checked the code and featured image is appearing.

Also, in which file did you keep these code?

So what does the resulting HTML look like?

@CBroe  

@NilambarSharma I keep these files in theme-name/assets/images, but I'm trying to make it so that anytime I upload a featured image on WordPress, it automatically changes the header image.

I am asking where you put this code because there is is_singular() which makes your code only working for single.php or similar singular template.

And style="background:inherit;');" data-bg="url('background: url('http://localhost/gs-llc/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/…) no-repeat contain" really looks like it should be, to you ...?

@CBroe Yes, it's the correct url for the image directly from WordPress. I don't want the image from my local filesystem. I want the featured image from my WordPress instance associated with the page.

@NilambarSharma Okay, I just took the is_singular() off but the code is in my front-page.php file. I also changed the header tag in my main wrapper since I recently moved it from header.php.

I finally figured it out! Instead of is_singular() and the code within the if statement, I deleted is_singular() and replaced the code within the if statement with the_post_thumbnail_url(); and that worked perfectly while also moving the extra CSS to the inline CSS of the div.
My reference for this answer came from here
